# Difference between planar sub-continua and sub-continua on the surface $\mathbb{T}^2$?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Can anyone tell me what is the essential difference between planar sub-continua and sub-continua of the torus? I will appreciate if you can give me some references.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. I am interested in continua, it is known that torus  is the quotient space of the unit square by pasting the opposite edges together, if $p$ is the quotient map, and  $K$ is a sub-continuum of the unit square, what does the image $p(K)$ look like? Or if $L$ is a sub-continuum of the torus, what is the pre-image $p^{-1}(L)$ of $L$?